# How to create my elements in chat using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm developing a chat, and I need to create the elements using JavaScript, but I don't have a lot of knowledge about JavaScript, so every time I try, it goes wrong, and I believe this is because of the CSS classes too, it makes it harder for me, I would like someone to help me with this

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

.chat {
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  height: 500px;
  /* border: solid 1px pink; */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  overflow: auto;
}

.messages {
  margin-top: 30px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.message {
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 4px 15px;
  margin-top: 1px;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.yours {
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.yours .message {
  margin-right: 25%;
  background-color: purple;
  position: relative;
}

.yours .message.last:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -7px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background: purple;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
}

.yours .message.last:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -10px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 20px;
  background: black;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}

.mine {
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.mine .message {
  color: white;
  margin-left: 25%;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #00D0EA 0%, #0085D1 100%);
  background-attachment: fixed;
  position: relative;
}

.mine .message.last:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: -8px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #00D0EA 0%, #0085D1 100%);
  background-attachment: fixed;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
}

.mine .message.last:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 0;
  right: -10px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 20px;
  background: black;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}

.yours .user {
  font-size: 0.6em;
  color: grey;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
}

.mine .user {
  font-size: 0.6em;
  color: grey;
  margin: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="chat">
  <div class="mine messages">
    <div class="user"><span>Me</span></div>
    <div class="message last">
      Dude
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="yours messages">
    <div class="user"><span>Mark</span></div>
    <div class="message">
      Hey!
    </div>
    <div class="message">
      You there?
    </div>
    <div class="message last">
      Hello, how's it going?
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="mine messages">
    <!-- <div class="user">Me</div> -->
    <div class="message">
      Great thanks!
    </div>
    <div class="message last">
      How about you?
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="yours messages">
    <div class="user"><span>Anne</span></div>
    <div class="message">
      Hello!
    </div>
    <div class="message">
      How are you?
    </div>
    <div class="message last">
      Glad to see you?
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="mine messages">
    <!-- <div class="user">Me</div> -->
    <div class="message">
      Great thanks!
    </div>
    <div class="message last">
      How about you?
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**How can I create this elements using JavaScript?**

Comment: It would have to dynamically determine which is the first/last message as they come in.

Comment: Could you help me please? I have no experience with JS

Comment: Do you want to convert a transcript to messages?

Comment: What I want is that, every time the user clicks the button, he sends a message, using JavaScript, and I want him to use these classes, and to determine who is sending and correctly positioning the elements, do you understand me?

Comment: Hi Anne, while there's nothing wrong with your request, SO is not meant for people to ask others to write their code. Search the net for *'build a simple chat system in javascript'* and you will find many examples how build a chat...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can render a message transcript by binning them by user and then rendering each of the bins.

Each time the underlying transcript is updated, just re-render the messages.

**Edit:** I changed:

```js
if (currBin.type === binType(message))
```

to this:

```js
if (currBin.from === message.from)
```

Because I was attempting to cache the users so that I only display a new user when they enter the chat (following a previous user) as seen in OP's HTML. You could have a flag to only show "Me" when a bin from the receiving user initially send a sequence of messages.

### Demo

```js
const messages = [
  { "from": "Me"   , "content": "Dude" },
  { "from": "Mark" , "content": "Hey!" },
  { "from": "Mark" , "content": "You there?" },
  { "from": "Mark" , "content": "Hello, how's it going?" },
  { "from": "Me"   , "content": "Great thanks!" },
  { "from": "Me"   , "content": "How about you?" },
  { "from": "Anne" , "content": "Hello!" },
  { "from": "Anne" , "content": "How are you?" },
  { "from": "Anne" , "content": "Glad to see you?" },
  { "from": "Me"   , "content": "Great thanks!" },
  { "from": "Me"   , "content": "How about you?" }
];

const renderMessages = (messages) => {
  const binType = (message) => message.from === 'Me' ? 'mine' : 'yours';
  const binMessages = (messages) => {
    const createBin = (message) => {
      return {
        'type': binType(message),
        'from': message.from,
        'messages': [ message ]
      };
    };
    return messages.reduce((bins, message) => {
      if (bins.length === 0) {
        bins.push(createBin(message));
      } else {
        const currBin = bins[bins.length - 1];
        if (currBin.from === message.from) {
          currBin.messages.push(message);
        } else {
          bins.push(createBin(message));
        }
      }
      return bins;
    }, []);
  };
  const render = (bins) => {
    return bins.map(bin => {
      return `
        <div class="${bin.type} messages">
          <div class="user"><span>${bin.from}</span></div>
          ${bin.messages.map((message, index, all) => {
            return `
              <div class="message ${index === all.length - 1 ? 'last' : ''}">
                ${message.content}
              </div>`
          }).join('')}
        </div>
      `;
    }).join('');
  }
  return render(binMessages(messages));
}

document.querySelector('.chat').innerHTML = renderMessages(messages);
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

.chat {
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  /* border: solid 1px pink; */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  overflow: auto;
}

.messages {
  margin-top: 30px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.message {
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 4px 15px;
  margin-top: 1px;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.yours {
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.yours .message {
  margin-right: 25%;
  background-color: purple;
  position: relative;
}

.yours .message.last:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -7px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background: purple;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
}

.yours .message.last:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -10px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 20px;
  background: black;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}

.mine {
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.mine .message {
  color: white;
  margin-left: 25%;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #00D0EA 0%, #0085D1 100%);
  background-attachment: fixed;
  position: relative;
}

.mine .message.last:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: -8px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #00D0EA 0%, #0085D1 100%);
  background-attachment: fixed;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
}

.mine .message.last:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 0;
  right: -10px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 20px;
  background: black;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}

.yours .user {
  font-size: 0.6em;
  color: grey;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
}

.mine .user {
  font-size: 0.6em;
  color: grey;
  margin: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="chat"></div>
```

Comment: Wow! Amazing code. Thank you so much, you're such a great dev

Comment: @AnneRebb I modified one of the conditionals above. I realized that I abandoned a user cache that I was originally going to add.

Comment: Great, thanks! Could you chat with me by email? I would like you to help me with one more question, I really need you, I can pay. Please call me: shibiaburame22@hotmail.com

Comment: @AnneRebb if you have follow-up questions, please submit a new question.